# Не срабатывает правило для второго объекта при :focus на первый

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать "переключатель" из двух стрелок. При нажатии на любую из них она меняет цвет на противоположный, тоже самое происходит со второй. (Реализуется с помощью спрайта и background-position).
Сейчас работает только смена позиции фона у той стрелки на которую нажал, вторая не меняется. Подскажите, где я накосячил ?

```css
.arrow {
 width: 38px;
 height: 28px;
 background-image: url("../img/spritesheet.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.left {
 background-position: -5px -5px;
}

.left:focus {
 background-position: -52px -5px;
}

.left:focus .right {
  background-position: -101px -5px;
}

.right {
 background-position: -149px -5px;
 margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<a href="##" class="arrow left"></a>
<a href="##" class="arrow right"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы написали `.left:focus .right`, что значит класс .right который лежит в .left.
Нужно поставить между ними `+`

```css
.left:focus + .right {
  background-position: -101px -5px;
}
```

Comment: Как я и думал, все просто. Большое спасибо)